# How to replace a string in a list if it contains a substring in Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [13,62,53, 33],
                   'gender': ['male','female','male', 'male'],
                   'symptoms': [['acute respiratory distress', 'fever'],
                                ['acute respiratory disease', 'cough'],
                                ['fever'],
                                ['respiratory distress']]})


df
```

Output:

```
       age    gender    symptoms
0       31      male    [acute respiratory distress, fever]
1       62      female  [acute respiratory disease, cough]
2       23      male    [fever]
3       33      male    [respiratory distress]
```

I am trying to replace all instances of values in the 'symptom' column (which are lists in this case) that contain the substring "respiratory", and change the entire value in that list to "acute respiratory distress" so it is uniform through out the data frame. This is the desired outcome:

```
Output:

       age    gender    symptoms
0       31      male    [acute respiratory distress, fever]
1       62      female  [acute respiratory distress, cough]
2       23      male    [fever]
3       33      male    [acute respiratory distress]
```

I have tried:

```
df.loc[df['symptoms'].str.contains('respiratory', na=False), 'symptoms'] = 'acute respiratory 
distress'

print(df)
```

The data frame remains as it was however.

Comment: Elements in `df['symptoms']` are of type list, not string. `df['symptoms'].str.contains` does not work as you want, because it is expecting a string not a list.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [13,62,53, 33],
                   'gender': ['male','female','male', 'male'],
                   'symptoms': [['acute respiratory distress', 'fever'],
                                ['acute respiratory disease', 'cough'],
                                ['fever'],
                                ['respiratory distress']]})

df['symptoms'] = [['acute respiratory disease' if 'respiratory' in s else s for s in lst] for lst in df['symptoms']]
       
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   age  gender                            symptoms
0   13    male  [acute respiratory disease, fever]
1   62  female  [acute respiratory disease, cough]
2   53    male                             [fever]
3   33    male         [acute respiratory disease]
```

Comment: Thanks! That produced the result I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Join the `explode`, then use `contains` assign

```
>>> s = df.symptoms.explode()
>>> df['symptoms'] = s.mask(s.str.contains('respiratory'),'acute respiratory distress').groupby(level=0).agg(list)
>>> df
   age  gender                             symptoms
0   13    male  [acute respiratory distress, fever]
1   62  female  [acute respiratory distress, cough]
2   53    male                              [fever]
3   33    male         [acute respiratory distress]
```

Comment: Thanks @YOBEN_S, this was a helpful technique